# Strange results using CGAffineTransformIdentity

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, core-graphics

I have several UI elements in a nib that are positioned using autolayout and constraints. When the view loads i move the elements off screen using

```
[self.button setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.button.frame.origin.x * 2 + self.button.frame.size.width, 0)];
```

then when the view appears i use the following to ease the button into the correct position on the page. However it seems to move too far across.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [self.button setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Am i doing something wrong? Is there a better way to move the button off the screen with CGAffineTransform?

Any help would be great

Comment: It seems like the button's original frame is not what you expect it to be. Where is the button if you comment out first line of code here that moves the button off of the screen.

Comment: The button appears on screen in the correct position if i comment out the first line which is why i am confused as to why CGAffineTransformIdentity isnt working. I am guessing its something to do with autolayout and constraints

Comment: first of all: you should use block-based animation instead.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by autolayout and the best way to animate UI elements when using autolayout is to change the constraints